# Shift `QGraphicsTextItem` position relative to the center of the text?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a number of classes that inherit from `QGraphicsItem`, that get to be arranged in a certain way. For simplicity of calculations, I made the scenes, and items, centered in (0, 0) (with the `boundingRect()` having +/- coordinates).

`QGraphicsTextItem` subclass defies me, its `pos()` is relative to top left point.

I have tried a number of things to shift it so it centers in the text center (for example, the suggested solution [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/51168-QGraphicsTextItem-center-based-coordinates) - the code referenced actually cuts my text and only shows the bottom left quarter).

I imagined that the solution should be something simple, like

```
void TextItem::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    painter->translate( -boundingRect().width()/2.0, -boundingRect().height()/2.0 );
    QGraphicsTextItem::paint(painter, option, widget );    
}
```

the above "sort of" works - but as I increase the item scale -> increase the font, the displayed item is cut off...

I tried to set the `pos()` - but the problem is, I still need to track the actual position on the scene, so I cannot just replace it.

A slightly unpleasant side effect - centering the `QGraphicsView` on the element does not work either.

How can I make my `QGraphicsTextItem` show its position relative to the center of the text ?

**Edit:** one of the experiments of changing the `boundingRect()`:

```
QRectF TextItem::boundingRect() const
{
    QRectF rect = QGraphicsTextItem::boundingRect();
    rect.translate(QPointF(-rect.width()/2.0, -rect.height()/2.0));
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: I think if you override paint(), you have to also override the boundingRect(), so that the painted text lies in the rectangle returned by boundingRect().

Comment: I tried, when I try to "translate" the `boundingRect()` I end up with a cut off text... (see edit for code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to shift the initial position, as well as the resize, to trigger a new position - I was unable to do it in paint() because, as I thought from the start, any repaint would continuously recalculate the position.

Only the initial position needs to be adjusted - but as the font size (or style...) changes, its bounding rectangle also changes, so the position must be recalculated - based on previous position.

In the constructor,

```
setPos(- boundingRect().width()/2, - boundingRect().height()/2);
```

in the function that modifies item (font) size,

```
void TextItem::setSize(int s)
{
    QRectF oldRect = boundingRect();
    QFont f;
    f.setPointSize(s);
    setFont(f);
    if(m_scale != s)
    {
        m_scale = s;
        qreal x = pos().x() - boundingRect().width()/2.0 + oldRect.width()/2.0;
        qreal y = pos().y() - boundingRect().height()/2.0 + oldRect.height()/2.0;
        setPos(QPointF(x, y));
    }
}
```